# Override array size in subclass

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance

I have an array as a member of a class. In a subclass, I would like to re-define the array with a different size. I want to do this because I anticipate making many subclasses, each with only the array size it needs, and nothing more.

```
class Foo
{
    Foo() {ivar = 1};
    int thisArray[2];
    int ivar;
}

class Bar : public Foo
{
    Bar() {ivar = 3};
    int thisArray[4];
}

int main()
{
    Foo myFoo;
    Bar myBar;

    Foo fooCollection[] = {myFoo,myBar};

    cout << "myFoo array size = " << sizeof(myFoo.thisArray)/sizeof(int) << endl;
    cout << "myBar array size = " << sizeof(myBar.thisArray)/sizeof(int) << endl;

    for (int n=0;n<2;n++)
    {
        cout << "fooCollection[" << n << "] array size = ";
        cout << sizeof(fooCollection[n].thisArray)/sizeof(int) << endl;
    }
    for (int n=0;n<2;n++)
    {
        cout << "fooCollection[" << n << "] ivar = ";
        cout << fooCollection[n].ivar << endl;
    }

}
```

My results are:

```
myFoo array size = 2
myBar array size = 4
fooCollection[0] array size = 2
fooCollection[1] array size = 2
fooCollection[0] ivar = 1
fooCollection[1] ivar = 3
```

I get that, since I declare the array objects as objects of class `Foo`, that referring to `myBar` within that scope would reference `myBar` as though it was a `Foo` and consequently interpret the size of `thisArray` as equivalent to 2. I also understand why `ivar` comes out the way it does.

Is there a way to affect the size of `thisArray` within the `Bar` class so its "correct" size can be recognized within an array of `Foo` objects? I would use a vector, but they are not friendly on the arduino platform. I could also simply make the array within the Foo class with a size of 100, but I am trying to be conscious of memory allocation.

Comment: Unrelated, but important: Look up "constructor initializer lists".

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use polymorphism?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use the STL containers that take care of all this re-allocation for you?

Comment: Use an array of pointers `Foo *fooCollection[]`, `Bar` objects are larger.

Comment: My base class has a lot of members which I would like to inherit in the subclasses. The only thing I really want to change is the size of the member array.

Comment: Please post compilable code. The code you shown has several errors and cannot even be compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this: `cout << sizeof(fooCollection[n].thisArray)/sizeof(int) << endl;`, it is impossible to know the size of `thisArray` because you are not using actual polymorphism. So the compiler assumes all elements in `fooCollection` are simpy `Foo` (static binding).

Start by using pointers:

```
Foo * fooCollection[] = { &myFoo, &myBar };
```

And declaring a virtual member that will know at **runtime** the size of the array. (dynamic binding)

```
virtual int size() {return sizeof(thisArray);}
```

And then rewriting to:

```
cout << fooCollection[n]->size()/sizeof(int) << endl;
```

Answer (score 10):

You could template your base class:

```
template <size_t Size>
class FooBase
{
    // etc....
    int thisArray[Size];
};

class Foo : public FooBase<2> { ... };

class Bar : public FooBase<4> { ... };
```

Of course, this is only practical where everything derives from `FooBase` -- that is, you don't have a class that derives from `Bar` which needs a different array size.

Also, as has been said in comments, if you need to keep these in an array you need to store pointers.

```
Foo myFoo;
Bar myBar;
Foo * fooCollection[] = { &myFoo, &myBar };
```

Oops, there I have assumed that `Bar` derives from `Foo`, which it no longer does.  If you want a common base that isn't templated, you need to derive the templated class `FooBase<Size>` from another base `FooType` and now use an array of `FooType`.  I think that will work.

```
class FooType {
  public:
      // etc...
      virtual size_t GetSize() const = 0;
};

template <size_t Size>
class FooBase : public FooType
{
  public:
    // etc...
    virtual size_t GetSize() const { return Size; }

  protected:
    // etc....
    int thisArray[Size];
};
```

And then:

```
FooType *fooCollection[] = { &myFoo, &myBar };
```

Comment: You could also have the template classes be derived from a common base, no?

Comment: Yes I believe so, and I have put a comment in my answer to that effect, as you need something that you can grab a pointer to when you wanna store all these instances in an array.

Comment: The syntax you suggested is giving me errors, such as "FooType has no member variable named 'thisArray'" when I try to enter `FooType* collection[] ...` I will look further into templates

Comment: Because you're trying to subvert the object oriented principles.  Make a pure virtual function on `FooType` called `GetSize()`, and implement it in the templated class to return `Size`.  I have edited the code at the bottom of my answer to illustrate.

Comment: paddy, i implemented your changes and they worked. templates may be a great way of doing things going forward. thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

You can define your array as a pointer and then `new` it with your constructor and `delete` it in your destructor. Remember the Rule of Three and you will be fine.

This is unless I've totally misunderstood your intent of this program.

Comment: Thanks! I implemented this strategy and it works for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion would be to not allow the base class to be a concrete class:

1. Let the base class be a abstract class providing interfaces to the
   array (size of array, read and write to the array).
2. Let the construction and destruction of the array be controlled by the
   derived classes.

This way, each derived class can choose the length of its array as appropriate.

Code sketch:

```
class foo {
  public:
    virtual size_t array_size() const = 0;
    virtual int *  array_base() const = 0;
    int array_get( size_t index ) const {
      array_verify_index( index );
      return *( array_base() + index );
    }
    void array_set( size_t index, int value ) {
      array_verify_index( index );
      *( array_base() + index ) = value;
    }
  private:
    void array_verify_index( size_t index ) const {
      assert( index < array_size() );
    }
};

class bar : public foo {
  public:    
    bar() {
       array_base = new int[ BarArraySize ];
    }
    ~bar() {
      delete [] array_base;
    }
    virtual size_t array_size() const {
      return BarArraySize;
    }
    virtual int * array_base() const {
      return array_base;
    }
  private:
    int * array_base;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll look into making a more abstract base class. It seems fitting for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well aware that I'm two years late, I would like to add another option - for those who seek an answer to this question without virtual methods or the new operator:

```
class Foo
{
protected:
    // Can only be constructed by Bar, or other derived type.
    Foo(int* _array, size_t _size) :
        array(_array), 
        arraySize(_size)
    {};
private:
    int* array;
    size_t arraySize;
};

template<size_t Size>
class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    Bar() : Foo(arrayData, Size) {};
private:
    int arrayData[Size];
};
```

This allows Foo to be a common 'array' interface for several classes, with no virtual methods and with stack allocated arrays. Only real drawback is that we, by necessity, inserted Foo::arraySize, but that's still for a relatively small cost (4/8 bytes on 32/64-bit).