# How can I redefine array size in a subclass?

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I have a base class in which I define an array of structs (of base types) and some methods that act on its objects; I never instantiate directly this class, just created varius sublasses of it. Now, in each subclass I would like to redefine the array size to the subclass particular needs.

Consider that I would like to avoid dynamic allocation in order to keep the program more dependable and because I like to see at compile time the amount of memory I'm using with my design.

I tryed by simply redefining the array in the subclasses; the compiler (I use Arduino IDE) does not complain about it but, from the amount of memory used reported by the compiler, I see that actually both arrays exist (the one defined in base class and the one "redefined" in the subclass) so it seems this is not the way to do it.

I found [a suggestion about using templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447281/12653751) but It hasn't received much approval, and because I read that templates are about making a class manage different data types, I think my problem of wanting just a different array size could have a more simple solution.

What is the correct way to obtain what I want?

Here is an example of my (wrong) code:

```
typedef struct {
    char val1;
    int val2;
} DataItem;


class BaseClass {
    DataItem dataItems[5];
};

class Sublass_A : public BaseClass {
    DataItem dataItems[50];
};

class Sublass_B : public BaseClass {
    DataItem dataItems[15];
};
```

Comment: You can have a pointer in `BaseClass` and assign the arrays to the pointer in the constructors of each class. Note the last class in the hierarchy will have all the arrays, so it'll be bigger. That can be fixed by using the heap, but that may not be what you want.

Comment: The template solution you linked to seems reasonable. templates can be used for types, as well as cases like this.

Comment: *because I read that templates are about making a class manage different data types* -- An array of 15 items is a different data type than an array of 5 items.

Comment: I agree with @cigien. Templates are actually used for compile-time computation, and for a case that is exactly like this: `std::array`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, I understand what you mean. I was thinking templates were the way to make a class manage apples and oranges, while I just wanted to manage different quantities of apples by using the methods of my base class, that already knows how to manage objects of apple type. Hence the doubt that there may be different solutions for the two tasks.

Comment: I tried the templates solution and worked perfectly, it was easiest than I expected. Thanks to everyone pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With template, you might do something like:

```
template <std::size_t N>
class ItemsArray {
    DataItem dataItems[N];
};

using classA = ItemsArray<50>;
using classA = ItemsArray<15>;
```

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42.
I accept this answer becuse it is the only and because it has put me on the right way.
For a total newbie like I dimostred to be about templates it was not so clear how to use the proposed solution, I had to search for other explainations and example code, so I will post another answer with the code of my question corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the initial code of my question, corrected following the [@Jarod42's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61916928/12653751).

```
typedef struct {
    char val1;
    int val2;
} DataItem;


template <size_t N = 5> // 5 is the default value if the size is not specified
class BaseClass {
    DataItem dataItems[N];
};

class Sublass_A : public BaseClass<50> {
};

class Sublass_B : public BaseClass<15> {
};
```

It compiles correctly and tests using sizeof() on the subclasses objects reported the expected sizes of the array.